# Quote a users comment in a thread

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I'm trying to build a reply function on an comment in a forum thread so when the user clicks reply it auto populates the reply box with the replied comment so they can add there reply underneath.

I have written a function in javascript to trigger on click to fill out the field.

```
    <script>
        function reply() {
            document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML = "{{ $comment->body }}";
        }
    </script>
```

This works but it only works first time and it fills out the  reply form with the last comment made, not the one I clicked on, I am having trouble how to determine which comment it is as it is in a for each loop.

```
            @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
            <div id="main">
                <!-- Comments -->
                <div class="post-box">
                    <article class="post">
                        <header>
                            <div class="title">
                                <p>Posted {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <a href="../profile/{{ $comment->user->id }}-{{$comment->user->name}}" class="author"><span class="name">{{ $comment->user->name }}</span><img src="{{ url('images/avatar.jpg') }}" alt="User Avatar" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                        <p id="comment">{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                        <footer>
                            <ul class="stats">
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-heart">28</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="reply-button">
                                <a href="#" onclick="reply()" class="button icon fa fa-reply">Reply</a>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    </article> 
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

Ideally I would also like the page to scroll to the buttom after the 'reply' is clicked and the cursor focus on the field (if someone could help with that, that would be great) but cross every bridge as I come to it.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I would give this your best attempt, and when you get stuck (even if it's very early on), post a new question and let us work through it with you. As this question is right now, it shows no effort and there's no starting point to work off of.

Comment: I've updated the post @Goose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Goose said, you really need to try out something yourself before posting a question on Stack Overflow. Nonetheless, since I see that you don't understand why your code is producing these results, I will be providing some help.

---

The reason your `reply()` javascript function always fills the `reply` text-area to be equal to the last comment in the page is simple. In your blade file you are looping through all the comments in a `foreach` loop. You keep each comment in the post's comments in your `$comment` variable. When your loop is finished, the `$comment` variable is equal to the last comment in your post. In a nutshell, the last value set to the `$comment` variable is the last comment in the post.

Now, at the bottom of your blade file you have your scripts. This is **after** your foreach loop. Thus, when you instruct blade to echo the body of the `$comment` variable with `{{ $comment->body }}` you are in fact telling it to echo out the body of the **last** comment, since that is the value of your `$comment` variable. Thus, whenever you run the Javascript `reply()` function, all you are doing is changing the innerHTML of reply to be equal to the body of the last comment in the post.

This is why you are getting these results.

---

To fix this (using plain Javascript) you will need to do something like this:

```
@foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
    ...
    <p class="comment-body" id="comment-{{ $comment->id }}">{{ $comment->body }}</p>
    ....
    <div class="reply-button">
        <a href="#" onclick="reply({{ $comment->id }})" class="button icon fa fa-reply">Reply</a>
    </div>
    ...
@endforeach
```

---

```
<script>
    function reply(id) {
        document.getElementById("reply").value= document.getElementById("comment-"+id).innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

**Edit:** make sure you use **`value`** like this => `document.getElementById("reply").value= document.getElementById("comment-"+id).innerHTML;` and **not** like this =>  <s>`document.getElementById("reply").innerHTML= document.getElementById("comment-"+id).innerHTML;`</s>

---

This, of course, is not the best solution. The best way would be to use vue.js or some other MVVM instead of this, well, hackery...

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I did understand the issue with identifying the comment because of the foreach loop and wasn't too versed with javascript hence why I asked

Comment: @user6073700, well, if this helps you then accept it as an answer so that the question closes.

Comment: I have one more question though, why does it not work after I clear the text field and try to repply to another comment?

Comment: If you follow my instructions, you shouldn't have such a problem.

Comment: Well here we are chief

Comment: is it because Im using an id? It literally will only work once I can't figure it out

Comment: Sorry, was kinda busy...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123076/discussion-between-theomessin-and-user6073700).